# WebBrowser Control Skip Expired Certificate

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, ssl-certificate

I am using WebBrowser Control in a delphi application to display some https web site.

But after navigating to it, I get web page with the following error: "The security certificate presented by this website has expired or is not yet valid." And there are options:

- Click here to close this webpage.
- Continue to this website (not recommended).

Is there way to suppress this error programmatically and continue navigating to this site as if security certificate was ok?

Comment: You'll need to change the security settings on the user's machine. I can't imagine anyone objecting to you doing that!

Comment: @David, who knows. OutlookExpress also uses InternetExplorer frame, but Fidolook used it to disable all dangerous features of Internet Explorer to make viewing mail safe. So, maybe there is. Though of course it is not recommended way.

Comment: I wonder if such certificate can be "imported" into Windows. Anyway, WebBrowser is Microsoft Internet Explorer, used via ActiveX. You'd better forward your question to MSIE guys. Probably you can globally disable MSIE security warnings on the machine. Maybe you can get some ActiveX interface out of WebBrowser, but i doubt Mirosoft allows those interface to disable security checks. Or maybe pure Delphi THTMLViewer would suite your need.

Comment: sure this is possible...

Comment: You can adjust the settings for the domain only, but in general it's a Bad Idea to suppress such warnings instead of fixing it. Either install the right certificate, or persuade the website owner to do it if it's not your site. If a proper certificate cannot be installed, i assume that security is not very important on this site, so you might as well check to see if you can access via http instead.

Comment: I wonder if (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/netfxbcl/thread/a00e2734-b8a0-4f90-a4d0-3cd8e0264944) or (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31163/Suppressing-Hosted-WebBrowser-Control-Dialogs) can be written in Delphi